# How can I set response type in API call just for one object in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, http

I have an API written in C# which sends an object data as json in which one of the data is in the form of byte[].
Model:

```
public class A {
int id;
string name;
byte[] data;
}
```

API:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/getdata")]
public IActionResult GetData()
{
  A a = new A
    { id= 1,
      name = "JOHN",
      data = { 0, 0, 0, 25 } 
     };
  return Ok(a);
}
```

When I call the same API in my angular application as:

```
getData(): Observable<A> {
    return this.http.get<A>(`${API_URL}/api/getdata`).pipe(
      map(data => data)
    );
  }
```

I have defined the same model A in my Client Side as well:
A:

```
export interface A {
id: number;
name: string;
data: ArrayBuffer;
}
```

But when I am calling the API the data is getting converted to base64 encoded string.
Is there a way so that I get Array Buffer only and I need not to write any extra method for conversion from base 64 string to Array Buffer.

I tried using :

```
getData(): Observable<A> {
   const httpOptions = {
     'responseType': 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
   };
    
   return this.http.get<A>(`${API_URL}/api/getdata`, httpOptions).pipe(
     map(data => data)
    );
}
```

but it's converting complete response to array buffer, where as I want arraybuffer just for **data** which is ArrayBuffer type.

Comment: JSON simply does not support byte arrays. Converting to and from base64 is the only valid option.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm The problem is I have 200MB of data in array buffer, so at front end side, converting the base 64 string to array buffer is crashing my browser.

Answer (score 0):

In respect of you comment

> @MoxxiManagarm The problem is I have 200MB of data in array buffer, so at front end side, converting the base 64 string to array buffer is crashing my browser.

This is a serious architecture issue then. No one should transfer 200MB of data in a json. Please think about providing the id of the data only and concat another requests with a respective response type (arraybuffer or blob) to retrieve the data.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data